# How can i change json_encode value in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am getting value in ajax data on success like this:

```
[["United States", "2.545454", "3.65656"],["delhi", "4.656565", "2.342342"]]
```

How can I change into like this:

```
[['United States', 2.545454, 3.65656],['delhi', 4.656565, 2.342342]]
```

Comment: But why? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Surely it would be better to amend the source of the JSON data directly

Answer (score 2):

After you have parsed data to array , loop over the array and convert strings to numbers

```
data.forEach(function(item){
   item[1] = +item[1];
   item[2] = +item[2];    
});
```

You can also do this at server and send the values as numbers instead of strings

Since you mentioned `json_encode` will assume that is php.

You can use the option `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` in `json_encode()` to do it automatically

Comment: Good catch on that second part.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the numeric strings into float. That means you need to parse those values.

```
//for some json object called 'json'
json.stringyfloat = parseFloat(json.stringyfloat);


//for your code
var json = JSON.parse(<your input>);
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
{
    json[i][1] = parseFloat(json[i][1]);
    json[i][2] = parseFloat(json[i][2]);
}
```

Though what you probably should do is make sure that when you're creating your datastructure, you make the values you want to be as floats, floats.

Comment: Woops my bad, I mixed those up, you're very right. I will update right away.